# Marshalling linking exception when reading XML from namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I am trying to marshall the object and send it to JMS.
What could be the mistake I am doing?

```
QName qName = new QName("http://schema.gspt.net/EventCanonical/1.0","OrderType");
JAXBElement<OrderType> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement( qName, OrderType.class,orderType);
jaxb2Marshaller.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxbElement,sw);

javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
- with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: com.radial.notification.event.OrderType is not known to this 
context
```

This is the namespace in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://schema.gspt.net/EventCanonical/1.0" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://schema.gspt.net/EventCanonical/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

The classic way of doing it actually working

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(OrderType.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(orderType, sw);
```

Comment: What is `jaxb2Marshaller`? Is that a `JAXBContext`? If so, it's badly named. And if so, was it created with `OrderType` as one of the registered classes, i.e. with `OrderType` "known to the context"?

Comment: Your comment help me to resolve the issue . The class is from org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller .  I went inside and saw that we have an option to set the classes to bound .

Comment: marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(OrderType.class) . This solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the classes to bound solved the problem

```
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(OrderType.class)
```